# UITableView header doesn't listen to scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, scroll, uitableview

I have a simple UITable and i want a little image before the table starts, so i use a tableheader so far so good, this works quite nicely

```
self.table.tableHeaderView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:img]];
```

only the weird thing is when i try to scroll on a table view row the table scrolls but when i try to scroll on the header nothing happens, its like the scroll listener isnt listening to to the scroll event on the header.

Just to be clear the header does scroll when you scroll the table as one piece ( and that is the desired behaviour )

Im googleling like crazy but kant seem to find the answer, thanks!!

some extra code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];
// set the table header
self.table.tableHeaderView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header"]];

// add empty footer view to hide empty cells
self.table.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];



// set title
self.navigationItem.title = [self.catData objectForKey:@"titlePage"] ? [self.catData objectForKey:@"titlePage"] : [self.catData objectForKey:@"title"];



}
```

Comment: do you want to scroll Header view while scrolling table rows or NOT ?

Comment: nope, i want the scrolling to work as explained. So just 1 table with 1 table header that whole table needs to scroll, this works. Only it doesnt work when you put your finger on the header and try to scroll, it does on the table rows... this is very frustrating :) thanks!!

Comment: can you provide more code here so I can see where you are going wrong

Comment: just added the extra code, dont think is helpfull though.... thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use Grouped Tableview. then you can scroll your table view.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting your header view with :

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:img]];
}
```

Comment: sorry, this is for fixing the header as i beleve. But i dont want a section header, i just want a image at the beinning of the table that scrolls with the table content

Comment: Do you use the section headers for something else ? Otherwise i believe it is a good workaround.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but these sectinons are fixed in the view ( absolute position on scrolling ), i need sections that move with the table cells, so this doenst work. Ive tested it, and the headers genereated by this function arent able to drag-scroll asswel :S thanks for the reply though

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement this below method:--

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
      CGRect rect = self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame;
      rect.origin.y = MIN(0, self.tableView.contentOffset.y);
      self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame = rect;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this is an answer to fix the header, i want to enable the scrolling.